# File transmission between two computers via ssh

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have two computers(lets name them A and B) with linux (two raspberry pi 3 ).
I need to get file from B and see it on A.
So I connected them with ssh.

B code file contains:

```
import rospy
from clever import srv
rospy.init_node('telemetry')  
file = open("telemetry", "w+")
while True:
  get_telemetry = rospy.ServiceProxy('get_telemetry', srv.GetTelemetry) 
  position = get_telemetry(frame_id='aruco_map')
  f.write(get_telemetry)
```

call here a rospy Service Proxy,then write
necessary info  into the file "telemetry",which I 
created on both raspberries.This part works fine.

Code file on A contains

```
import subprocess
while True:
  subprocess.call(["ssh","pi@B", "'cat telemetry'", ">", "telemetry"])
```

B is raspbbery ip and pi is login

But when i run code file on A it says "bash: cat telemetry: command not found"
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You're trying to run the program `cat telemetry` on the remote host, and it obviously doesn't exist. To copy files, use scp, not ssh.

Comment: Note that `ssh` just concatenates all its arguments together into one command and invokes it in a remote shell. There is absolutely no difference whatsoever between `['ssh', 'pi@B', 'cat telemetry >telemetry.copy']` and `['ssh', 'pi@B', 'cat', 'telemetry', '>telemetry.copy']`.

Comment: ...by contrast, `cat`ing a file to itself will always just delete the file, because the output redirection happens **before** the version of `cat` supposed to do the read is even started!

Comment: ...and, more pertinently, your current code is equivalent to `['ssh', 'pi@B', "'cat telemetry' > telemetry"]` -- the `>` is still an argument to `ssh`. If you want to know what a shell command equivalent to that would look like, the following Python will generate one: `import pipes; print(' '.join(pipes.quote(x) for x in ['ssh', 'pi@B', "'cat telemetry' > telemetry"]))`

Comment: NB You should consider using SFTP to fetch the file rather than a command through plain SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `subprocess.call`, you don't need to add extra quotes because spaces are not delimiters. Also, since the shell is not involved locally, output redirection with `>` doesn't work. The `>` will be sent to remote host and will run remotely. To redirect the actual local command to a file, you must use subprocess `PIPE` output capturing by passing a parameter named `stdout`:

```
with open('telemetry', 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.call(["ssh", "pi@B", "cat telemetry"], stdout=f)
```

That should fix your issue and answer your question "What am I doing wrong?" - however, as others have pointed out in the comments, you should consider using `scp`, `sshfs` or even a `paramiko` session instead of running a remote `cat` to copy files.

Comment: A shell **is** involved -- one is started on the remote side by `ssh`. As such, the redirection is not at all a noop -- it has the effect of truncating the `telemetry` file before `cat` can read it!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good catch, added a clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using Python Fabric ([HERE](http://www.fabfile.org/)). It's very easy to configure. You just make a connection a call a function:

```
from fabric import Connection
C = fabric.Connection('IP', user='pi', connect_kwargs={"password": "raspberry"})
result = C.put('myfile', remote='/home/pi')
```

I use it for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks,will try it